# how to lay out a complex app and its views/regions/layouts

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Even after reading some nice tutorials and blogposts on how to structure a Backbone Marionette app, I got confused while writing my own. Here is my setup.

I have an app that can easily be structured into different sub-apps (aka Backbone modules)
Click on a link in my main navigation bar starts one of these apps. That means it loads the apps starting layout into my #main div.

But these apps have different layouts in themself, so navigating inside the app overwrites regions specified in the main app layout.

e.g.

```
var myApp = Backbone.Marionette.Application()
...
var layout = myApp.myModule.layout = new Backbone.Marionette.Layout()
...
myApp.main.show(myApp.myModule.layout)
```

where layout has the following DOM tree each mapped to a region

```
#app_main
  .albums
  .artists
```

Then I do something like

```
layout.app_main.show(new myView())
```

and from now on I can not get access to layout.albums or layout.artists even after using the back button (using a Backbone.Router and History)

Should I split my module's main layout to contain only #app_main, and load the opening layout into it at a separate step? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Use events to communicate through the views. Raise these events on the models ( so that you can even subscribe to them through collection)

Answer (score 3):

It would help to know a little bit more about what you're going for, but here's a shot at an answer. Let me know if it helps!

Let's say this is your HTML layout:

```
<div id="app">
  <div id="app_nav">
    <a href="#music">Music</a>
    <a href="#books">Books</a>
  </div>
  <div id="sub_app"></div>
</div> <!-- /#app_main -->
```

For our "Music" sub-app, we'll use this template:

```
<script id="musicApp-template" type="template/html">
  <div class="albums"></div>
  <div class="artists"><div>
</script>
```

For the album item view:

```
<script id="album-template" type="template/html">
  <img src="<%=albumThumbSrc %>" />
  <p><%=albumTitle %></p>
</script>
```

For the artist item view:

```
<script id="artist-template" type="template/html">
  <%=firstName %> <%=lastName %>
</script>
```

--

For our "Books" sub-app, we'll use this template:

```
<script id="booksApp-template" type="template/html">
  <div class="books"></div>
  <div class="authors"></div>
</script>
```

For the book item view:

```
<script id="book-template" type="template/html">
  <img src="<%=bookThumbSrc %>" />
  <p><%=bookTitle %></p>
</script>
```

For the artist item view:

```
<script id="author-template" type="template/html">
  <%=firstName %> <%=lastName %>
</script>
```

And to bootstrap the app:

```
$(document).ready({
  myApp.start();
  if(!Backbone.history.started) Backbone.history.start();
});
```

--

Now to set up our Marionette views.

In myApp.js

```
var myApp = new Backbone.Marionnette.Application();

myApp.addRegions({
  subAppRegion: "#sub_app"
});

// Your data
myApp.artists = new Backbone.Collection([...]);
myApp.books = new Backbone.Collection([...]);
```

In myApp.musicApp.js

```
myApp.module("musicApp", function(musicApp, myApp) {
  /* Setup your Views
   ================== */
  var MusicLayout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: #musicApp-template",
    regions: {
      albumsRegion: ".albums",
      artistsRegion: ".artists"
    }
  });

  var AlbumView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#album-template"
  });

  var AlbumListView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView({
    itemView: AlbumView
  });

  var ArtistView = ...
  var ArtistListView = ...

  /* Create router for app navigation
   ==================================== */
  var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
      "music" : showMusicApp
    },
    controller: musicApp
  });
  new Router();

  /* Method to show the music app
   ================== */
  musicApp.showMusicApp = function() {
    // Instantiate Views
    var musicLayout = new MusicLayout();
    var albumListView = new AlbumListView({ collection: myApp.albums });
    var artistListView = new ArtistsListView({ collection: myApp.artists });

    // Show musicApp layout in subAppRegion of main app
    myApp.subAppRegion.show(musicLayout);

    // Show albums and artists in musicApp layout
    layout.albumsRegion.show(albumListView);
    layout.artistsRegion.show(artistListView);
  }
});
```

You can set up your `myApp.booksApp` module much the same way:

```
myApp.module("booksApp", function(booksApp, myApp) {
  ...
  var Router = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    appRoutes: {
      "books" : showBooksApp
    },
    controller: booksApp
  });
  new Router();

  booksApp.showBooksApp = function() {
    ...
    myApp.subAppRegion.show(booksLayout)
    ...
  }
  ...
});
```

I haven't tested all this code, so sorry if there are some kinks, and I'm sure it could be improved.

If you haven't already read [David Sulc's tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/05/06/tutorial-a-full-backbone-marionette-application-part-1/), you should take a look - it will give you  a better idea of a full fledged application. But I hope this gives you a basic idea of how you use layouts and regions to show different subApp views.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule in my own projects, I always keep elements defining regions empty and then load them dynamically in the `Layout.onRender` method. This has the added benefit in Marionette.Async that if I need to load additional data from the server before displaying the view in the region, I can do so in the view's `beforeRender` method.

One exception to my rule is showing an animated "loading..." div in the region's element which gets overwritten as soon as populate the region.